# Running x11vnc contigency

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, vnc, bash-scripting

Essentially I have this bash

name(start)

```
#!/bin/bash
x11vnc rfbport subport && x11vnc rfbport main port

source /home/Desktop/prime.sh;
```

name(prime)

```
#!/bin/bash
x11vnc rfbport mainport

source /home/Desktop/prime.sh
```

I would appreciate any advice as to possible syntax mistakes and as to whether this would work. And the purpose of this is essentially to prevent vnc from not working after it crashes, or a client leaves. The first script start is primarily for the crashing since if the shell stops working I figured the second shell waiting would function. However I quite literally started using linux yesterday so I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you probably actually want to use the `--loop` option to restart `x11vnc`

```
   -loop

          Create  an  outer loop restarting the x11vnc process whenever it
          terminates.  -bg and -inetd are ignored in  this  mode  (however
          see -loopbg below).

          Useful  for  continuing  even  if  the  X  server terminates and
          restarts (at that moment the process  will  need  permission  to
          reconnect to the new X server of course).
```